# Access properties from derived class

Tags: javascript, typescript, subclass

```
abstract class Base {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.components)
  }
  components = ['']
}
class Child extends Base {
  components = ['button', 'text']
}

const f = new Child()
```

Running this code, I get

```
['']
```

But I would rather like to get

```
['button', 'text']
```

from the derived Class. 
**Reason I want to do this:**
I want to validate the "components"-property, which the user defined in the Child. 
Is it not possible ?

Comment: Creating new `Child` class does not affect `components` property in superclass. It just calls constructor of superclass, which logs that class's `components`.

Answer (score 1):

The components property is being set just after the constructor in the base class has been called:

```
abstract class Base {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.components)
  }

  components = ['']
}

class Child extends Base {
  constructor() {
    // inherited components from base = ['']
    super() // Call base constructor

    // this.components = ['button', 'text']
  }

  components = ['button', 'text']
}

const f = new Child()
```

You need to wait for the base constructor to synchronously complete, before you can access the new values - ie. by using `setTimeout`:

```
constructor() {
  setTimeout(() => console.log(this.components))
}
```

---

Ideally you should pass the components as parameters:

```
abstract class Base {
  constructor(public components = ['']) {
    console.log(components)
  }
}

class Child extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super(['button', 'text'])
    // this.components = ['button', 'text']
  }
}

const f = new Child()
```

Comment: Thx, this seems to work ! But is it best practice, or rather does it work in all scenarios ?

Comment: Thanks, but I actually liked the first solution better, because the user of the Child class doesn't have to implement the constructor. So it would be easier to use (and less error prone..)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
abstract class Base {
  constructor(components) {
    console.log(components)
  }
}
class Child extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super(['button', 'text'])
  }
}

const f = new Child()
```

or

```
abstract class Base {
  constructor(components) {
    console.log(components)
  }
}
class Child extends Base {

}

const f = new Child(['button', 'text'])
```